# Can not access samba file share

Tags: network, macos, sharing, smb

I have activated file sharing for my public folder. I have network connectivity within my private local LAN and Internet Access. My router does not support IPv6.
When someone tries to connect from another mac with my shared folder, the login procedure is incredibly slow. I have tried to use the domain name and the ip-address without success.

Today I have learned about the mac tool smbutil and tried it for my own PC using smbutil view -g //hostname but I took very long and then the procedure failed.
I cannot

- find any logs (what does apple do with logs???)
- turn on smbd debug level
- find any clue to solve the problem in the Internet.

Can someone help me?

g

Answer (score 1):

I like using WireShark to do a packet capture. Wireshark can highlight the SMB traffic and allow you to see if the packets are flowing well. You can also analyze the SMB transactions. This is helpful because you can compare a Windows client and a macOS client to the same appliance with the same tool on the same network and see what the difference is.

You probably are negotiating the connection differently or may need the server logs to analyze what's happening not the client logs.